# I try to update the gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, updates

PS C:\Users\SIYI\OneDrive\Escritorio\Proyectos\Ventas\ForSale> gem update --system
`Installing RubyGems 3.4.15 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)     Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems`

Let the gems be updated

Answer (score 0):

Try running powershell in Administrator mode

Answer (score 0):

Use Command Prompt as an administrator; it worked for me. Just a simple piece of advice: as a web developer, it's better to use WSL in your Windows system.